# Is it possible to some how view or generate the architecture of an Rails application as a "map"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, shell

I´m pretty new to rails and have been building an App to learn by building it. I was thinking about it would be great if I could somehow generate a map of the App that I´m building. I don't know if map is the right term but what I mean is if I could somehow generate a schema or outline of the App were I could see all connections, database tables, relations, etc... of the app.

I'm using postgressql in the App if it makes a difference.

Comment: Railroady etc. There are others.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out @DaveNewton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rails-erd](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd) is a great gem which generates a Entity-Relationships datagram for your application, I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks @thiagotonon I´ll use this one